# Strange error with google-api-client in google app engine app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-client

We're restructuring our web app, which runs on GAE.  The POM was changed a bit.  But no significant other changes.

Now we get this strange error on one page of the app:

*You are currently running with version 2.2.0 of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.31.1 of google-api-client to run version 1.32.1 of the Cloud Storage JSON API library.*

What does this mean?

We weren't specifying a specific version of google-api-client in the POM.  However we did at a dependencymanagement section, which I have a feeling has something to do with this error.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>26.29.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

To resolve the problem I added this back into the POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.32.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However, I would like to know what is going on.  Thanks.

Comment: Not an expert with JAVA but generally (for Python, Node and I assume it will apply to other languages), if you don't specify a specific version for a library, Google will install the latest version it can find. This can be in conflict with another library which has a specified version. However, based on the wording of your error message, that higher version should have worked since the error says ```at least```. I suspect that error message was authored many releases ago when ```1.31.1``` was kind of new and they haven't also modified the code to work with higher versions of the library.